# Guided Tours Fail-on-Startup with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, servicenow

Just made several simple guided tours for forms in Kingston. Never had any issue with the tests starting on Chrome. When anyone tries to start any of my tests in IE (Update 11.0.95 where I'm at), a red box shows up on the screen saying "Tour ended because the next step was not found". No settings I changed in the browser could affect the problem.

I am aware that ServiceNow doesn't consider IE 11 a modern browser.

https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0683275

Changing isn't an option for me. Has anyone ever encountered this issue? Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

[Screenshot to go with below comment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMaQE.png)

Comment: I suggest you to provide a sample code or detailed steps to produced the issue. We will try to follow your steps and try to make a test with IE 11. I also suggest you to check the console if it displays any error message or not. You can try to make a test on any other machine with IE 11 to check whether this issue is machine dependent or not.

Comment: I have two systems running in different domains/environments. System with error: Windows 10, IE Update: 11.0.95, IE Version:11.0.10240.18036. System without error: Windows 7, IE Update 11.0.95, IE Version: 11.0.9600.19180. Steps to reproduce: Open servicenow. Open a record with a tour. Show the help sidebar. Click 'Take a tour' on the help sidebar. The System with error finishes these steps with the above screenshot. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide!

Comment: Is this tour developed using any code or created using some UI steps using any application? Try to check the console of Internet Explorer whether it is displaying any error or warning message. It can be helpful to find the issue.

Comment: There are no console errors. This happens with Guided Tours on custom forms as well as OOB forms.

Comment: It is possible that Service now is not compatible with Internet Explorer. I suggest you to move to MS Edge if you are working on Windows 10.